# Referencing the left cell in a table in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js function that needs to format the 6th column in a table according to the value in the 5th. I have used the following but it doesn't work:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(6)').each(
    function() {
      var vGood = 0.2
          good = -0.5,
          avg = 0,
          poor = 0.5,
          vPoor = -0.2
      score= $('tr td:nth-child(5)').text(); 
      if (score >= vGood) {
          $(this).addClass('fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg text-danger latest-icon');          
      }
})
```

Comment: What does it actually do? Any error shows up in the console? Please include the HTML fragment related to your code

Answer (score 5):

You have to use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to refer the correct `td` in each iteration. Also, since you are comparing the text with a float value, use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert the default string value of `td` to float.

Change

```
score= $('tr td:nth-child(5)').text();
```

To

```
score = parseFloat($(this).prev('td').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clean dom approach:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++){
    var cells = rows[x].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (parseInt(cells[4].innerText) > 0.2){
        cells[5].innerText = "very good";
        cells[5].className += "fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg text-danger latest-icon";
    }
}
```